# ffmpeg Add watermark/text in video on react native

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Right now i'm stuck on android part,here is my code

I don't want to define font styling or box it just i found this code somewhere so i just copy pasted it as i don't have any knowledge of ffmpeg, I just want a simple text of right aligned in 2 lines on top of right of the video like this.
[image: Expected output]

**I am getting the error in this part of code as the video is getting generated but it does not play and it is of always 262B size**

```
 String[] cmd = new String[] {
            "-i", path, "-vf", String.format("drawtext=\"fontfile=/systems/fonts/DroidSans.ttf: text='%s': " + "box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborder=5: x=(w-text_w)/t: y=(h-text_h)/2\"", text), "-codec:a", "aac", out.getAbsolutePath()
    };
```

**This is the full code**

```
@ReactMethod
public void embedTextOnVideo(String text, String path, int fontSize, String fontColor, final Callback successCallback, final Callback errorCallback)
{
 FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(_reactContext);
 try
 {
  ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}
  });
} catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
  // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
}

File out = getOutputFile(TYPE_VIDEO);

String[] cmd = new String[] {
        "-i", path, "-vf", String.format("drawtext=\"fontfile=/systems/fonts/DroidSans.ttf: text='%s': " + "box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborder=5: x=(w-text_w)/t: y=(h-text_h)/2\"", text), "-codec:a", "aac", out.getAbsolutePath()
};
try {
  ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {
      errorCallback.invoke("Error ffmpeg executing with message:\n\t" + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {
      successCallback.invoke("Successfully output file with message:\n\t");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}
  });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
  // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
}
}

@Nullable
private Throwable writeDataToFile(byte[] data, File file) {
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
  fos.write(data);
  fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  return e;
} catch (IOException e) {
  return e;
}

return null;
}
@Nullable
private File getOutputFile(int type) {
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;

// Create storage dir if it does not exist
if (!storageDir.exists()) {
  if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create directory:" + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
    return null;
  }
}

// media file name
String fileName = String.format("%s", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()));


enter code hereif (type == TYPE_VIDEO) {
  fileName = String.format("VID_%s.mp4", fileName);
} else {
  Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported media type:" + type);
  return null;
}

return new File(String.format("%s%s%s", storageDir.getPath(), File.separator, fileName));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to overlay the watermark?

Comment: i want to add watermark in video so that the final video should have the watermark in it always. @Dan

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I think you can help me in this

Comment: @RF You mentioned an error but did not include the actual error. Is the problem with your scripting or the ffmpeg command or both? Narrow down the issue by separating the ffmpeg command from the scripting. Run it manually, unscripted using the same command that the script executes. If it works then your script or the implementation of the ffmpeg command in the script is to blame. If it does not work then show the ffmpeg command and the complete log/console output from the command.

Comment: @RF Are you able to add text/watermark on video ? And if yes, then can you please suggest me some sample code.

Comment: @Priya That does not worked that time and we wanted something in hurry so what we did, front end uploaded the video as it is and then backend used ffmpeg package to add watermark and then replace the video